# Is is possible to use a mobile phone as a usb modem?

Tags: usb, modem, broadband, dongle, gsm

Is it possible to use the data allowance of a phone contract on a laptop?  At the moment, I have a usb dongle which I use when I need to use my laptop away from home.  Instead of using this dongle, can I make my phone act as a dongle?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I connect my laptop to internet through mobile phone using USB cable?](http://superuser.com/questions/162402/can-i-connect-my-laptop-to-internet-through-mobile-phone-using-usb-cable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can if your phone and your telco allow it.

I certainly do this with my Android phone on a pre-pay (PAYG) mobile phone account with O2. I use a USB cable (same one for charging, syncing data to PC) but you can also usually use a bluetooth wireless connection between phone and computer.

It is called "[tethering](https://superuser.com/search?q=tethering)"

See also [mobile broadband vs tethering, any benefits to dongles e.t.c](https://superuser.com/questions/12048/mobile-broadband-vs-tethering-any-benefits-to-dongles-e-t-c)

Note that many phone companies dislike tethering as they believe netbooks/tablets/desktops use more data bandwidth than mobile phones. Phones bundled with monthly contracts may have restrictions on tethering.

Comment: If tethering is turned on and used via usb, no one else can rob me of my data allowance can they?  That can only happen if I have tethering via bluetooth right?

Comment: You need to check with your provider.  If they disallow tethering on your plan, and you circumvent that rule they might detect your usage and charge you.

Comment: @oshirowanen: Tethering over a USB cable doesn't allow other people to make use of your bandwidth (unless you also make Internet access available over WiFi - some phones, including Android phones can act as a mobile WiFi router).

Answer (score 1):

Basically it depends whether your phone + carrier allow it.

Comment: I know that the carrier allows it, but I am about to upgrade my phone, and will make sure it has tethering functionality!

Answer (score 1):

If you have driver+tool that allows you to access your phone's functionality you can use it  . If you are on a linux machine all you need is Blueman .
And as Red mentioned if your carrier allows it , you can do it.Most of them do anyway (I am yet to encounter someone whose carrier doesn't allow it)

Comment: I'm assuming Blueman is for bluetooth tethering right?  How about Linux and USB tethering?