# need to use a gsm mobile phone as a gsm modem

Tags: windows, java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is is possible to use a mobile phone as a usb modem?](https://superuser.com/questions/336748/is-is-possible-to-use-a-mobile-phone-as-a-usb-modem)

Guys, I need to use my GSM mobile phone (specifically Nokia n95) as a GSM modem. Is there any way to do it in windows platform? Please give elaborate answer if possible.

Comment: What is the difference between "????" and just a normal "?"?.

Comment: it's an existential '?' it questions the fact that it questions questioning itself.

Comment: Now when someone accepts my edit you won't have to worry. And it will be more legible...

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming here that you want to use mobile's data connection on your PC.

The Nokia PC Suite and the new Nokia Suite have that function built-in.
Install either, connect the phone in "PC Suite" mode and the suite will have option to connect to internet.